# How to show that $\{\pm 1\}$ is a normal subgroup of $\mathbb{S}^3$ and is the nontrivial normal subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Do I need to work with the matrix representation of $\mathbb{S}^3$. I don't know how to begin on this question.

Comment: What is for you $\;\Bbb S^3\;$ ?

Answer (score 1):

As a Lie group $\mathbb{S}^3$ is diffeomorphic to $SU(2)$, which has center $C_2=\{\pm 1\}$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group). Hence it is a normal subgroup. It is easy to see that this is the only nontrivial normal subgroup by using a matrix representation (Pauli matrices). Or we could use that any nontrivial closed normal subgroup of $SU(n)$ is contained in its center (which was proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200499/normal-subgroups-of-sun)).