# Prove that $U(n)$ has no nontrivial normal subgroup except $Z(U(n))$.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I've been reading Naive Lie Theory by John Stillwell, and this is the first exercise that has started to feel hopeless. It is exercise 7.5.3. I was trying to use the strategy that was used earlier in the book for proving the simplicity $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C}), \mathfrak{su}(n), \mathfrak{so}(n),$ and $\mathfrak{sp}(n)$, now slightly altered since $\mathfrak{u}(n)$ is not simple. The section is about the Tangent Space Visibility Theorem which states that if $G$ is a path connected Lie group with a discrete center and a nondiscrete normal subgroup $H$, then the tangent space of $H$ at the identity is nontrivial, with the corollary that if $H$ is a nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$, then it's tangent space at the identity is a nontrivial ideal of $G$'s tangent space at the identity. Of course, $Z(U(n))$ is not discrete, so the theorem does not apply; it relies on finding a neighborhood of the identity that contains no elements of $Z(G)$ except the identity. The next paragraph thus may be pointless but I can think of no other approach.

So, assuming this is the correct route, we get a nontrivial (oh, and I've interpreted nontrivial here to mean "nondiscrete and not $U(n)$ itself" since otherwise there are the roots of unity which is a normal subgroup) subgroup $Z(U(n))$ from the ideal spanned by $\mathbb{i}I$, which commutes with every complex matrix and thus its Lie bracket with any skew-Hermitian matrix is $0$ and we can't get any elements not generated by this one dimensional basis. As in the simplicity proofs, I begin with some $X\in\mathfrak{u}(n)$ that is not in the ideal spanned by $\mathbb{i}I$. Let $A=E_{ij}$ be the matrix with all 0 entries except $a_{ij}=1$ and $a_{ji}=-1$ and $B=\tilde E_{ij}$ be the matrix with all 0 entries except $b_{ij}=b_{ji}=1$. Find some $x_{ii}\ne x_{jj}$, which must exist, since otherwise we are in the ideal that is the tangent space of $Z(U(n))$. Compute $[X,E_{ij}]=(x_{ii}-x_{jj})\tilde E_{ij}$ and $[X,\mathbb{i}\tilde E_{ij}]=(x_{ii}-x_{jj})\mathbb{i}E_{ij}$, which gives us basis elements $\mathbb{i}\tilde E_{ij}$ and $E_{ij}$. We can "translate" an $E_{ij}$ to get basis elements at other non-diagonal entries, with $ [E_{ki},E_{ij}]=E_{kj},[E_{ij},E_{j\ell}]=E_{i\ell},[\mathbb{i}\tilde E_{ki},E_{ij}]=\mathbb{i}\tilde E_{kj},$ and $ [E_{ij},\mathbb{i}\tilde E_{j\ell}]=\mathbb{i}\tilde E_{i\ell}$, and something similar can be done if the basis element you start with is $\mathbb{i}\tilde E_{ij}$. We can finally get $n-1$ more basis elements by Lie bracketing $[E_{in},\mathbb{i}\tilde E_{in}]=-2\mathbb{i}(\tilde E_{ii}-\tilde E_{nn})$ as in the simplicity proof for $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ where the trace was required to be 0. Any imaginary scalar matrix would suffice as a final basis element, but I am unsure how to arrive at one, and even if I did, I am unsure how I would apply the section's proof, yet I am do not know how else I could approach this problem if I cannot apply the proof. I'd like any insight on this problem as I feel I've spent too long thinking about it for a textbook exercise, yet it doesn't seem like I'll be able to solve it without help. $U(n)$ has not been talked about as much as the groups with simple ideals, but it was important in the complexification section where it was shown that $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})=\mathfrak{u}(n)+\mathbb{i}\mathfrak{u}(n)$, though I don't see how this would be relevant.

This is a duplicate of [Normal subgroups of $U(n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3162976/normal-subgroups-of-un), I will note, which is in turn labelled as a duplicate of another problem; however, as the poster of that question notes, it really should not have been labelled a duplicate as the linked question there instead asks about $SU(n)$, which has a simple Lie algebra. So, the first person to ask this question never had it answered. This is my first question here but I hope it meets the criteria. I will appreciate any help but I am looking for an answer within the scope of this book, which focuses exclusively on matrix Lie groups, and so everything written in it uses methods and ideas that are intended to be used with matrix Lie groups. This is my first experience with Lie groups and I may not understand the reasoning behind a more general proof that applies to all Lie groups, namely this one, but cannot be proven with the linear algebra methods of this book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exercise has a typo, I assume, since it directly contradicts Exercise 5.5.2 from the same book. $U(n)$ has a normal subgroup, namely $SU(n)$. I guessed originally that the exercise was to prove that $SU(n)$ has no normal subgroups other than those contained in $Z(SU(n))$, but this is proved earlier in the section.

So I have no idea now what the author wanted to ask. Since $SU(n)$ is a normal subgroup of $U(n)$, the kernel of the determinant map, there are normal subgroups of $U(n)$ containing $SU(n)$ as well.

Comment: Even the updated wording is not completely correct (unless $n$ is prime): any subgroup of the center is normal.

Comment: @JasonDeVito This is absolutely true. Updating...

Comment: Now I read the rest of that section, it's already proved that normal subgroups of $SU(n)$ are central. So I have no idea what the author was asking for.

Comment: Huh. You are right and I had already done that exercise exactly as you said. I had interpreted nontrivial differently than the author usually does, as meaning no proper subgroups that weren't contained in the center, since I noticed the problem was obviously wrong otherwise, but I hadn't considered $SU(n)$ itself, just $Z(SU(n))$. I'll skip this problem then and stop letting it take up space in my mind. I guess my feeling that the problem didn't seem to fit in this section due to having a nondiscrete center was justified. Thank you!