# Finite normal subgroups of $\operatorname{SU}(n)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups, normal-subgroups

We know that the center of the special unitary group $\operatorname{SU}(n)$ is

${\bf Z}(\operatorname{SU}(n))={\mathbb Z}/n.$

Inspired by these questions:

1. [The finite subgroups of SU(n)](https://mathoverflow.net/q/17072/27004)
2. [Normal Subgroups of $SU(n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1200499/79069),

I like to ask what are the finite normal subgroups of $SU(n)$?

For example, the center of the special unitary group $SU(n)$ is
${\bf Z}(SU(n))={\mathbb Z}/n$. When $n=$ odd integer, it seems to not include the ${\mathbb Z}/2$ as a center. So can the ${\mathbb Z}/2$ be part of a normal subgroup of $SU(n)$? (especially for $n=$ odd?) Is this statement true or false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is already answered by Qiaochu Yuan in your second link. Any finite normal subgroup of $\textrm{SU}(n)$ must be contained in its center. Since $Z(\textrm{SU}(n))\cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},$ these are exactly the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},$ that is the groups of matrices generated by $\omega_m I$ for $m|n$ where $\omega_m$ is a primitive $m$th root of unity.

Comment: thanks so much. Can you clarify (1) why "Any finite normal subgroup of SU() must be contained in its ℤ/ℤ center"?  and (2) how about a finite subgroup of SU() that may not be contained in its center?

Comment: @wonderich Qiaochu Yuan gives a good answer to (1) in the second link. Answering (2) is equivalent to giving a matrix of finite order not contained in the center. As an example, $\begin{bmatrix} e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}}\end{bmatrix}.$

Comment: I hope that your answer is canonical, I accept it for now - if you or someone else finds any issue, please do update :)